# Roman pagenumbering + \usepackage[greek]{babel}

Tags: page-numbering, babel

I have the problem that the roman or Roman pagenumbering does not work if `babel` is used with `greek` option. Does not work means, that the pages itself have correct numbers but the table of contents will show only the number the toc is on. Any suggestions what might help?

In case you want to proof yourself:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\addchap[Preface]{Preface}
\blindtext

\addchap[Thank You]{Thank You}
\blindtext

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Test}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with an up to date TeX Live 2013

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong. Everything seems OK to me in the TOC.

Comment: Indeed, I was not aware that my system was so outdated! Sorry, I should have tried this at first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug already solved in a new version of the relevant package.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem. Specifically, Roman page numbers were not listed in the index. A workaround is to manually enter the Roman page numbers, for instance by `\renewcommand{\thepage}{iii}`.